# Text view clipping of in android

Tags: android

I am using a custom Toast and sometimes the text view  gets clipped off if the field is too long:

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toast" >

   <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/someotherview"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/someotherview"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/someotherview"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried virtually everything starting from android:gravity="fill" to android:ellipsize="marquee". Nothing seems to work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would help you: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/autoscale-textview/

It re-sizes the textview (and the text) to fit in your other view.

Comment: There must be some mistake I am making. I dont think an external library is required just to prevent clipping of a textView. Is there any way to do it in the xml

Comment: Well it really depends on a lot of factors. Let's say you have a 100 chars long message. You would then need to have a screen width of at least ~800px. But if you only have short messages, say 30 chars at max all chars would fit on screen, hence no clipping will occur. But i would suggest you to, if applicable, use a linearlayout instead of a relativelayout and use either fill_parent or match_parent on the textview.

Comment: I have several other text views too, aligned to the right and left of each other. Using a linear layout would not make any sense.I am using wrap_content to automatically set the size of the TextView. It should automatically expand since the relative layout is also wrap_content